# How to do arithmetic operations on two columns from two different files with row offset in gnuplot?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I need to plot data from two CSV files. Column 1 from file1 starting from row 1 to 50 for x.
For y I need to include arithmetic operation between file 1 and file 2. I want to use file 1 column 2 row 1-50 and divide it by file2 column 2 from row say 10-60 each.
I am using Windows platform and VS code for editor to execute. I am new and currently have very limited knowledge. Can you please give or give me a guide how to plot this?

I am struggling how to merge and plot with mathematical expression at the same time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @ASD. Lots of people will be willing to help you, but you'll need to provide data sufficient to create a reproducible example. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Do you mean row 10-59 or row 11-60? If you want to do arithmetic operations it should be the same numbers of rows as 1-50.

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide any data so, I will create some test data files (actually, numbers from 0 to 99 in column 1 and their square numbers in column 2).

As I understand, you want to do arithmetic operations with data from two files and additionally with some row offset.

One possible solution would to put the relevant data of x and y (without and with row offset) into arrays `X`, `Y` and `D` and then plot the arrays and do the arithmetics by index. You are using the command `stats` which is actually for statistics (which you are here not interested in), but using it for putting the data into arrays.

For further reading: check in the gnuplot console `help stats`, `help array`, `help every`, `help pseudocolumns`. Note, that row indices are zero-based in gnuplot.

For your case skip the test data section and replace the filenames with your filenames.

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=5.2.0 because the use of arrays)

```
### calculations with data from two different files and different rows
reset session

FILE1 = "SO77339533_1.dat"
FILE2 = "SO77339533_2.dat"

# create some test data
set table FILE1 separator comma
    plot [0:99] '+' u 1:($1**2) w table
set table FILE2 separator comma
    plot [0:99] '+' u 1:($1**2) w table
unset table

set datafile separator comma
n1 = 1      # start row
n2 = 50     # end row
d3 = 10     # row offset
array X[n2-n1+1]
array Y[n2-n1+1]
array D[n2-n1+1]
stats FILE1 every ::n1-1::n2-1 u (X[int($0-n1+2)]=$1) nooutput
stats FILE2 every ::n1-1::n2-1 u (Y[int($0-n1+2)]=$2) nooutput
stats FILE2 every ::n1+d3-1::n2+d3-1 u (D[int($0-n1+2)]=$2) nooutput

plot X u (i=int($0+1),X[i]):(Y[i]/D[i]) w lp pt 7 lc "red" notitle
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind effort, I was able to merge two files using python code into one file and then it was easier for me.

Comment: I'm impressed. Demonstrates the power of gnuplot.